# C - adding to an Char Array and Int

Tags: c, arrays

Basically, I have an array being passed as a pointer to a function, which capitalizes the first letter, the strlen of that array is also being passed.

What I want to do, after capitalization, is to then append '1' to the end of the array, so that `hello` becomes `Hello1`. But I am unsure how to do such thing in code, or whether its possible.

```
...
char myString[70];  <-- Array being passed, where the string is never > 64 char's.
...

void capFirst(char *s, int i) {
    s[0] = (toupper(s[0]));
}
```

EDIT: Solutions below do the following:

```
1Security
1Sebastian
1Schumacher
1Sanderson
```

EDIT:

```
void capFirst(char *s, int i) {
 s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
 s[i] = 1;
 s[i+1] = '\0';
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int i;
int j = 0;
char fileSave[256];
char myString[50];
FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    fpIn = fopen(argv[i], "rb");
    snprintf(fileSave, 256, "%s~[%d]", argv[i], i);
    fpOut= fopen(fileSave, "wb");
    while((fgets(myString, 49, fpIn)) != NULL) {
        if(isspace(myString[0]))
            break;
        j = strlen(myString);
        if( (j > 8) && (j < 64) ) {
            capFirst(myString, strlen(myString));
            fprintf(fpOut, "%s", myString);
        }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
void capFirstappOne(char *s, int i) {
    s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    s[i] = '1';
    s[i+1] = '\0';
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int i; int j = 0;
char fileSave[256];
char myString[50];
FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    fpIn = fopen(argv[i], "rb");
    snprintf(fileSave, 256, "%s~[%d]", argv[i], i);
    fpOut= fopen(fileSave, "wb");
    while((fgets(myString, 64, fpIn)) != NULL) {
        j = strlen(myString);
        if (j > 0 && (myString[j-1] == '\n')) {
            myString[j-1] = '\0';
        }
        if( j > 8) {
            capFirstappOne(myString, strlen(myString));
            fprintf(fpOut, "%s\n", myString);
        }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are passing the wrong 'i', i.e i will be 0 when you sent. You gotta call the function as capFirst(myString, strlen(myString));

Comment: It still adds it to the beginning :/

Comment: @user1048116 Post the code how you call the function. If you call it with `capFirst(myString,strlen(myString))`, where `capFirst` is modified as in Chethan Ravindranath's answer, the only possibilities that the '1' is put at the front are 1. a completely broken toolchain, 2. you don't use `strlen` as provided by the implementation.

Comment: Ah, it puts the '1' right at the end, but the `fgets` leaves the newline in the string, so you get e.g. "Sebastian\n1" and the '1' appears on the next line, right before the next name.

Comment: Use strcat() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if the array is large enough):

```
s[i] = '1';
s[i + 1] = 0;
```

Comment: It adds it to the beginning :/

Answer (score 1):

You ***must*** be sure that the array have enough space to take an extra 1 towards the end. And do not miss to terminate the string with `'\0'`.

```
void capFirst(char *s, int i) {
    s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    s[i] = '1';
    s[i+1] = '\0';
}
```

Or use `strcat()` function.

```
void capFirst(char *s, int i) {
    s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    strcat(s, "1");
}
```

The full program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void capFirst1(char *s, int i)  
{
    s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    strcat(s, "1");
}

void capFirst2(char *s, int i)  
{
    s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    s[i] = '1';
    s[i+1] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[10] = {"hello"};
    char b[10] = {"world"};

    capFirst1(a, strlen(a));
    printf("a = %s\n", a); 

    capFirst2(b, strlen(b));
    printf("b = %s\n", b); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That places it at the beginning of the array :/

Comment: 1Security
1Sebastian
1Schumacher
1Sanderson

Comment: @user1048116 I have placed complete working code for your reference.. If you find it working, please confirm so by clicking the tick mark against the above answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Sangeeth Saravanaraj like this: '1'

Comment: @DanielPersson Its a funny thing. I was thinking you were asking me to add " (read double quotes) around the `i` and was as wondering why?! .. Now figured out that you meant " (read two single quotes)!! .. Thanks for your clarification. I've updated the code accordingly!

Comment: @user1048116 If you find the above post answers your question, please confirm so by clicking the tick mark against the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function appears to put the '1' at the front of the string because the string originally ends with a newline. So when appending a '1' to that, the result looks like "Sebastian\n1". When these strings are printed to the output file - without any separators - the result looks like

```
Sebastian
1Schumacher
1Sanderson
1
```

When reading a file with `fgets`, check whether a newline has been read, and if the newline is not supposed to be part of the string in further processing, remove it (overwrite it with '\0'). When writing to a file with `fprintf`, it prints out only the characters it is passed, it doesn't add any separators, be it spaces or newlines, so one has to add the desired separators oneself.

In your code,

```
while((fgets(myString, 49, fpIn)) != NULL) {
    if(isspace(myString[0]))
        break;
    j = strlen(myString);
    if( (j > 8) && (j < 64) ) {
        capFirst(myString, strlen(myString));
        fprintf(fpOut, "%s", myString);
    }
}
```

to remove unwanted newlines, you could, after `j = strlen(myString);`, insert

```
    if (j > 0 && myString[j-1] == '\n') {
        myString[--j] = 0;
    }
```

Then a newline would be overwritten (`fgets` doesn't read more than one newline) and the variable holding the length decremented accordingly. You needn't recompute `strlen` then, you can call `capFirst` with

```
    if (j > 8) {
        capFirst(myString,j);
        fprintf(fpOut, "%s\n", myString);
    }
```

In the condition, you need not check `j < 64` because you told `fgets` to not read more than 48 characters (49-1, one for the 0-terminator), so that is a given. In the snippet above, I've added a newline to the format string, so each string is printed on its own line. If you don't want that, you could use `"%s "` to separate the strings with spaces, "%s," for commas etc.

Comment: Any chance of a clue on how to do this? I can't work it out exactly where I need to check, and what you mean by add the desired seperators.

Comment: After adding your suggestions, it still fails to work :( Thoroughly confused as the above made sense to me.

Comment: and it continues not to append the 1

Comment: Updated. Above in orignal post.

Comment: Works here as intended. Very odd.

Comment: Do you think its something to do with any given text editor, i am just using notepad to open the output files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6205/discussion-between-user1048116-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it

```
char myString[70];
.....
void capFirst(char *s, int i) {
    s[0] = (toupper(s[0]));
    s[i] = '1';
    s[i+1] = 0;//NULL Termination
}
```

Comment: It adds it to the beginning :/